# Error while deploying Solr 3.5 on Jboss 5.1

Tags: jboss, solr, jboss5.x

I am trying to deploy solr 3.5 in Jboss 5.1 server. I've modified the
WEB-INF\web.xml to set the solr home by adding the following:

```
<env-entry>
<env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
<env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
<env-entry-value>E:\apache-solr-3.5.0\example\solr</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Now when I start jboss I get this error. The wiki says remove
xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar
and xml-apis-1.3.03.jar from WEB-INF\lib in solr.war. But I don't see these
jars in that location for Solr 3.5.
Thanks.

```
13:30:39,614 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse:
name=vfsfile:/E:/jboss/server/default/deploy/solr.war/ state=PreParse
mode=Manual requiredState=Parse
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object
for vfsfile:/E:/jboss/server/default/deploy/solr.war/
at
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49)
at
org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:362)
at
org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:322)
at
org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:294)
at
org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.deploy(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:234)
at
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
at
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
at
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
at
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
at
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
at
org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
at
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
at
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
at
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:403)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:778)
at
org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:543)
at
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.registerProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:308)
at
org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:256)
at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source:
The content of element type "env-entry" must match
"(description?,env-entry-name,env-entry-value?,env-entry-type)". @
vfsfile:/E:/jboss/server/default/deploy/solr.war/WEB-INF/web.xml[47,14]
at
org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:203)
at
org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:168)
at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:189)
at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:166)
at
org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:137)
at
org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:121)
at
org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parseAndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:304)
at
org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parseAndInit(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:286)
at
org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:203)
at
org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:348)
... 33 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: The content of element type
"env-entry" must match
"(description?,env-entry-name,env-entry-value?,env-entry-type)". @
vfsfile:/E:/jboss/server/default/deploy/solr.war/WEB-INF/web.xml[47,14]
at
org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser$MetaDataErrorHandler.error(SaxJBossXBParser.java:426)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown
Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown
Source)
at
org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown
Source)
at
org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at
org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:199)
... 42 more
```

Comment: "for fun" try it with tomcat on the same machine.

Comment: It's a known bug in SOLR 3.5 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2718 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3084 (better ask in Solr user mailing-list, IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

It is late to post an answer, perhaps, but the solution was so easy (and time-consuming, if you do not already know it!) that I thought I had to share it! Hoping this helps…

Uncomment the block looking like this:

```
  <!-- People who want to hardcode their "Solr Home" directly into the
       WAR File can set the JNDI property here...
   -->
  <env-entry>
     <env-entry-name>/solr/home</env-entry-name>
     <env-entry-value>/the/path/to/your/solr/home</env-entry-value>
     <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  </env-entry>
```

but put the `env-entry` node as the last child of the `web-app` node, and not as the first (like in the original `web.xml` file).
Then you're gone.

I personally tested it on a JBoss AS 6.0.0 installation over a Ubuntu Linux machine (OpenJDK for Java v. 1.6.0_24 / IcedTea6 1.11.4), with Solr 3.6.1.